# Is glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) necessary when I already glDisable(GL_BLEND)?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In my understanding, if I disable `GL_BLEND`, then no blending happens at all.
So I don't need do `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`.

I am working on GLES20 for Android programming. I have added the line below.

```
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

If I don't add `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`, all other devices work well except Nexus 4.
On Nexus 4, on one pass (other passes work normally), only partial area is rendered.
If I add `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`, then now Nexus 4 works well.

Comment: The context for your question is not complete enough to give a simple answer. Is depth test enabled? Stencil? How much of the framebuffer is rendered? What is the viewport? Etc. In the absence of details the answer is "probably yes."

Comment: I don't enable depth test, stencil test. But why are they related to color buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`GL_BLEND`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glEnable.xml) is disabled, then a fragment of the draw buffer will be overwritten, if it is drawn to.
If you disable blending and you write on every fragment of the draw buffer in every frame, then it is useless to clear the draw buffer, because each fragment will be set during the drawing process.
[`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glClear.xhtml) does nothing else than to write to every fragment with a constant color set by [`glClearColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glClearColor.xml).

Note, you have to ensure, that every fragment is written in each frame. For example if `GL_DEPTH_TEST` is enabled you'll have to [`glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glClear.xhtml) anyway.

Comment: Thanks. That was I thought. Without glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) all other devices work as expected except Nexus 4. So I guess that might be due to something weird in Nexus 4.

Comment: then in my case, do you think it is something wrong with Nexus 4?

Comment: I have explicitly used glDisable(GL_BLEND). And it works well on other devices. So I also thought it was bug with that device. Thanks.